# Tabwidget overlaps with my activity content

Tags: android, overlap, tabwidget

after spending 2 solid days searching for an answer, I would like to ask for help about the following behaviour.

I'm trying to code a simple tabhost application on Android, with a layout per activity.
I've designed my layout so that the tabwidget appears at the bottom of the screen.

On the first tab, I'm trying to insert a simple 2 lines ListView. My problem is that the ListView is well on the bottom, but half of it is hidden behind the tabwidget. I would like to understand how to make my ListView to be displayed just above the tabwidget.

Here is my main.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

       <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />

       <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Here is my main app class :

```
public class TestTabWidget extends TabActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AActivity.class);

        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Tab A",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_a))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);


        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }

}
```

Here is my Activity code :

```
public class AActivity extends Activity {

ListView lvListe;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.a_layout);
        lvListe = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvListe);
        lvListe.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.tables);

        String[] listeStrings = {"Value 1","Value 2"};

        lvListe.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listeStrings));

    }
}
```

Here is my layout for the activity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView 
          android:id="@+id/lvListe"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks to anyone keen to help me I'm just going nuts....

Adam

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this layout instead for your `RelativeLayout` section:

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent">

  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs"
    android:padding="5dp" />

  <TabWidget
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Right now, your `FrameLayout` is filling the entire space inside the `RelativeLayout`, as `RelativeLayout` makes no distinctions about placing items next to each other like `LinearLayout` does, and allows overlapping.  My adjustment tells the layout to fill the space between the widget the the top of that layout.

Another note about `RelativeLayout`, the Z-order of the items is determined by the order in XML, that's why the `TabWidget` appears on top of the `FrameLayout`.  If you had reversed the order, the `TabWidget` would not have even been visible!

Hope that helps!